# Oracle SQL find missing sequence in varchar2 field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and to this forum. I have searched and found answers on how to do this with a column of just numbers but this has txt at the beginning then a sequenced number.

I have a table that has a varchar2 column named  myid which has characters with a number at the end which is in order the number at the end is always 6 digits with leading zeros.

```
Hello_002190  
Hello_002188  
Bye_000187  
Bye_000185  
Bye_000184  
Get_008133  
Get_008131  
Gone_001112  
Gone_001110  
Gone_001109
```

I need an Oracle SQL script that will show me all the missing rows.
The result for the above should be:

```
Hello_002189  
Bye_000186  
Get_008132  
Gone_001111
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can we assume that the min and max values are define in the already existent values in your table? Do you know how to use RegEx? I believe we can achieve this...

Comment: I am not familiar with RegEx but I will look it up and read about it to become familiar with it. Thanks for the question. The min max are not specifically defined they would have to be determined by the last 6 characters of the field.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb885b/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Hello_002190' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hello_002188' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bye_000187' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bye_000185' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bye_000184' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Get_008133' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Get_008131' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gone_001112' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Gone_001110' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 'Gone_001109' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( prefix, suffix ) AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, INSTR( value, '_' ) ),
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( value, INSTR( value, '_' ) + 1 ) )
  FROM   table_name
),
bounds ( prefix, min_suffix, max_suffix ) AS (
  SELECT prefix, MIN( suffix ), MAX( suffix )
  FROM   data
  GROUP BY prefix
)
SELECT prefix || TO_CHAR( column_value, 'FM000000' ) AS missing_value
FROM   bounds b
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT b.min_suffix + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY b.min_suffix + LEVEL - 1 <= b.max_suffix
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
MINUS
SELECT value FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb885b/6/0)**:

```
| MISSING_VALUE |
|---------------|
|    Bye_000186 |
|    Get_008132 |
|   Gone_001111 |
|  Hello_002189 |
```

Comment: MT0,  Thank you very much. Very nice. I will give this a try on Monday. Some of what you did is unfamiliar to me but I am investigating what you did.  Very much appreciated.